# Can I use any smart card to run Sim Toolkit applications?

Tags: applet, smartcard, sim-toolkit

I have an ordinary Simcard. I want to use SimToolkit to write applets using active commands. when I use nothing special my applet is installed on my sim, but when I set specific events, this applet cannot be installed anymore.

Is there anything I have to install on my Simcard before installing my own applet? Is there any prerequired applet or other materials I have to install on my Simcard to run active command applets?